# Fill link text with target nodes title field

Tags: entities, navigation

In a content type im using a link field to link to internal pages.
When such a content type is created i want that the (internal) URL is added to the link field and it pulls the links text automatically from the target nodes title field. I do not want the link text being entered as separate field.
E.g when "PageA" has a link field and the links points to "PageB" (with URL "http://www.sitename.org/node/731"), and PageB has a title "This is page B" the link on "PageA" should read "This is page B" and not "http://www.sitename.org/node/731".
I tried the different formatters for the link field, but none is pulling the target pages title. Also Tokens do not offer the option to pull the nodes title.

Has anyone done this already?

Comment: If you could consider changing the field to an entity reference field this is the default behavior.

Comment: As @PontusNilsson pointed out [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) or [References](https://drupal.org/project/references) provide this functionality. Also formatters only affect what gets output on the front end/theme and doesn't necessarily affect node forms.

Comment: Yes EntityReference is alright, and additionally offers auto-completion. Thanks for pointing me to this!
Link was just the most intuitive option as i am not deeply familiar with all the different modules.